# Why do I have different result set between SELECT * and SELECT Column1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a Stored Procedure where I am using a string function in my `WHERE` in order to pass multiple parameter values.
But why it works fine if I say

```
WHERE  
   cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT ClassCode 
                    FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

But it gives me complete different incorrect result if I say:

```
WHERE 
    cc.ClassCode  IN (SELECT * 
                      FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

In both cases `@ClassCode = '31439,68189,01239,41894...'` the same order of values, whether its `SELECT ClassCode FROM` or `SELECT * FROM`

What is the logic behind?

Full query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LossesByStateTest
    @ClassCode nvarchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT      
        pc.Quoteid, pc.PolicyNumber, pc.AccidentDate,
        cc.TransactionEffectiveDate, cc.ClassCode,
        CASE
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.QuoteID, pc.PolicyNumber, cc.AccidentDate ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) = 1 
               THEN pc.PaidLosses 
               ELSE 0
        END  as PaidLosses--,
    FROM
        tblLossesPlazaCommercialAuto pc 
    INNER JOIN
        tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial cc ON pc.PolicyNumber = cc.PolicyNumber 
                                        AND pc.AccidentDate = cc.AccidentDate
                                        AND cc.AccidentDate IS NOT NULL
    --WHERE cc.ClassCode   IN (SELECT ClassCode FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode,','))    --Works fine
    WHERE  
        cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))     --- doesn't work
END
```

Function is below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable]
    (@Strings varchar(8000),
     @Separator char(1))
RETURNS @StringTable TABLE (String varchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @String varchar(500), @Pos int

    SET @Strings = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Strings))+ @Separator
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Strings, 1)

    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Strings, @Pos - 1)))

        IF @String <> '' 
           INSERT INTO @StringTable VALUES (@String)

        SET @Strings = RIGHT(@Strings, LEN(@Strings) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Strings, 1)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

@scsimon I am so sorry. It didnt work because the way I supplied my parameter values in SP was written in a column and the apostrophe was on the other line. I added a picture above. 
Incorect way:

[image]

See where the last apostrophe?

And this is correct way:

[image]

Comment: Can we see the function?

Comment: Added. 
Function was made a long time ago by professionals and been used forever. 
Thanks

Comment: Wait, I actually just noticed that it gives me the same result even if I pass different parameters

Comment: So I'd suggest using one of these splitters and joining to your results. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings. It's a great read that's often referenced

Comment: And look at that last @pos setter

Comment: Honestly, this function is a little bit too much for me so far. But I passed values and it returns me a column with all `ClassCode`'s I passes. So I assumed it works correctly.
So whats with the last `@pos`?

Comment: Sorry @Oleg, I was on my mobile last night. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get incorrect results with:

```
WHERE  
   cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT ClassCode 
                    FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

is because there is no Column `ClassCode` in your return table, `@StringTable`. In your function you declared your return table, `StringTable`, with the column `String` as so:

`RETURNS @StringTable TABLE (String varchar(500))`

Thus, you are selecting a column which doesn't exist when you attempt the statement above. However, these two statements should produce the same results:

```
WHERE  
   cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT String
                    FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))

WHERE  
   cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT *
                    FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

**TEST DATA**

```
declare @table table (ClassCode varchar(16))
insert into @table (ClassCode) values
('31439'),    --this is in @ClassCode
('01239'),    --this is in @ClassCode
('41894'),    --this is in @ClassCode

('00000'),    --this is NOT in @ClassCode
('12345'),    --this is NOT in @ClassCode
('somev')     --this is NOT in @ClassCode

declare @ClassCode varchar (8000) = '31439,68189,01239,41894' --if this is NULL nothing is returned, which is what should happen

select * from @table where ClassCode in( select * from [StringOfStringsToTable] (@ClassCode,','))
select * from @table where ClassCode in (select String from [StringOfStringsToTable] (@ClassCode,','))
```

Comment: No the shouldn't. You are wrong in this case. But it is common error so i can forgive you :).

Comment: Why is that @Deadsheep39

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But honestly if I ran it as
`WHERE  
   cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT *
                    FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))`
it still gives me some weird result. I guess something with function

Comment: You have to define weird @oleg. What were you expecting with what Input compared to what was given?

Comment: If I say `WHERE  cc.ClassCode   IN (SELECT DISTINCT ClassCode FROM tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial )`  I got over 500,000 records with all ClassCodes, which is more than 200 of them.
But if I ran as:
`WHERE  cc.ClassCode   IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode,','))` then I got only 439 rows with only 2 different ClassCodes

Comment: Interesting and thank you for the explanation. This gives me something to research.

Comment: So, if I run this:
`DECLARE @ClassCode varchar(max) = ('31528,67497,01499,739899,50428,42592,50249,40272,21483,33239')
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode,','))`
it gives me 10 rows in one column. 
Isn`t it supposed to be one row with 10 values?
Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128879/discussion-between-oleg-and-scsimon).

Comment: @oleg i provide a test data, and i can't reproduce what is happening in yoru query. Perhaps it's somewhere else in your code.

Comment: After running a TEST DATA both SELECT statements return same ClassCodes: 31439  01239  41894

Comment: @scsimon I am so sorry. It didnt work because the way I supplied my parameter values in SP was written in a column and the apostrophe was on the other line. I added a picture above.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks for the update. Your function probably read that as char(13)+char(10)

Comment: Yes.Probably. I had no idea this can completely effect the result. Sorry again, and thank you very much for your time and persistence.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I think you also can change the where clause to

```
WHERE  CHAINDEX(','+cc.ClassCode+',',','+@ClassCode+',')>0
```

Comment: `CHARINDEX`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is BIG!

```
WHERE cc.ClassCode  IN (SELECT * 
     FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

This is working when you have only ONE output column from your TVL. If you have more columns then your qry is in background rewrited to exists qry:

```
WHERE cc.ClassCode EXISTS (SELECT * 
     FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

And this qry is always true. Or for better imagine you can rewrite it:

```
WHERE cc.ClassCode  IN (SELECT cc.ClassCode 
     FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ','))
```

So you have to specify one output column or use condition:

```
WHERE cc.ClassCode IN (SELECT *
     FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ',') t
     WHERE cc.ClassCode = t.ClassCode )
```

It is the common error when you use in `IN` condition column which isn't in subset existing --> is always true.

Comment: And can be output null? If can be null you have to add where mycol is not null...

Comment: No since the function isn't created with default NULL values set to the parameters

Comment: I have no testing case, but i think on null input there is null output from TVL. To test is null isn't problem or it is easy to test my previous answer.

Comment: It tells me on `t.ClassCode` `Invalid column name 'ClassCode'.`

Comment: Am I missing something simple?

Comment: No @Oleg this goes back to there not being a column in the TVF names that

Comment: I have change it to 
`WHERE cc.ClassCode IN ( SELECT *
           FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@ClassCode, ',')  t
           WHERE cc.ClassCode = t.String )`
But unfortunately I still receiving 400 rows with two different ClassCodes

Comment: try ... WHERE cc.ClassCode = t.String and t.String is not null

Comment: Just tried. Still the same. Have no idea what is going on

Comment: I am joining many to many relationship.  Can it cause the problem?
But again, it works fine if I say
`WHERE  cc.ClassCode   IN (SELECT DISTINCT ClassCode FROM tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial )` which returns me more than 500,000 rows

Answer (score 0):

I should be more careful when supply parameters to the Stored Procedure that uses Split string function.
The reason I had incorrect result because of the way I supplied parameters:

```
EXEC SP_Name @ClassCode ='31439,
68189,67139,68528,68128
,33428,739889,5561
'
```

So I should not break a supplied string. 
And this it the correct way:

```
EXEC SP_Name @ClassCode ='31439,68189,67139,68528,68128,33428,739889,5561'
```